# Can NULL be a constraint like NOT NULL in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, null, constraints

```
create table t1(ider number null);
```

Does it behave as:

```
create table t1(ider number check (ider is null));
```

or

```
create table t1(ider number default null);
```

?

Comment: Why would you want this constraint? What's the point of having a column that is always null for every record?

Comment: You want a field that is *always* `NULL`???

Comment: This SQL just defines a table with a single column of type `number` which *can* be NULL - nothing else. It does **not** define a default value, nor does it enforce a check constraint on the column

Comment: I suppose this question is here for grammar curiosity. So I just voted +1 contrarily to others.

Comment: Sure you can, just like I can create a constraint on an integer column such that it can only assume the value 42. Not terribly useful as others have commented, but certainly permitted by the grammar. You may be misunderstanding what "NULL" and "NOT NULL" mean when defining a field. "NOT NULL" of course means "cannot be null". "NULL" means CAN be null, not MUST be null.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

None of your two hypotheses.

Oracle takes `NULL` in a column specification as the **explicit absence of a NOT NULL constraint**. It is a (misleading) no-op in a `CREATE TABLE` statement, but not necessarily in an `ALTER TABLE` statement where it can revoke a previously existing constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE t(col1 TYPE NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY col1 NULL; -- Now the `NOT NULL` constraint has been dropped
```

Therefore when you use `CREATE TABLE t(c INTEGER NULL)` it does not mean that `c` should be always null, nor does it mean that `c` has default value `NULL`. It just means that `c` being null **is ok**.

[image: screenshot taken on Tora]

Comment: just for info, that happens in `Sybase ASE` as well :)

Comment: +1.  Despite all the down- and close-votes, this is actually a good question.  Btw, here's how the manual explains it: "The NULL keyword by itself does not actually define an integrity constraint, but you can specify it to explicitly permit a column to contain nulls."  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/clauses002.htm#SQLRF30038

Comment: I think both the question and answer are worth an upvote.  This is a bit of Oracle DDL syntax I hadn't thought about before - glad to know it now.

Comment: A not for those who work across database types, MS SQL Server can be set to have the default be `not null` such that if you wanted a column to be able to hold null values the `null` keyword would have to be used in `create table`. So it is a no-op in Oracle, but not everywhere. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187356

Answer (score 0):

### If you want to do it you can!

For example, the following works..

```
create table #tempe (
valor int null
)

insert into #tempe values(null)

select * from #tempe
drop table #tempe
```

### **But.. why? oO**